# Create Flow chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, networking, sankey-diagram, ggalluvial

I am trying to make either a multi node Sankey or Alluvial plot whichever is  more appropriate.

The output would be similar to this which is from the `ggalluvial` packgage vignette here [gg alluvial vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html)

[image]

The difference would be that my `time_period` would be on the x axis  and  my `source` column would replace the survey responses.  I also tried the Sankey plot from the `networkD3` package for a single time period to get results similar to below from the vignette here [Sankey Plot](https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/sankey.html)

[image]

Which would be a good compromise  if I cant visualize all the time periods  but it did not work either.  My sample data and code is below. Thanks

Data

```
  dat = structure(list(time_period = c("1 -> 2", "1 -> 2", "1 -> 2", 
"1 -> 2", "1 -> 2", "1 -> 2", "1 -> 2", "1 -> 2", "1 -> 2", "1 -> 2", 
"1 -> 2", "1 -> 2", "1 -> 2", "1 -> 2", "1 -> 2", "1 -> 2", "2 -> 3", 
"2 -> 3", "2 -> 3", "2 -> 3", "2 -> 3", "2 -> 3", "2 -> 3", "2 -> 3", 
"2 -> 3", "2 -> 3", "2 -> 3", "2 -> 3", "2 -> 3", "2 -> 3", "2 -> 3", 
"2 -> 3", "3 -> 4", "3 -> 4", "3 -> 4", "3 -> 4", "3 -> 4", "3 -> 4", 
"3 -> 4", "3 -> 4", "3 -> 4", "3 -> 4", "3 -> 4", "3 -> 4", "3 -> 4", 
"3 -> 4", "3 -> 4", "3 -> 4", "4 -> 5", "4 -> 5", "4 -> 5", "4 -> 5", 
"4 -> 5", "4 -> 5", "4 -> 5", "4 -> 5", "4 -> 5", "4 -> 5", "4 -> 5", 
"4 -> 5", "4 -> 5", "4 -> 5", "4 -> 5", "4 -> 5"), source = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D"), target = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", 
"D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", 
"B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"), count = c(200573, 
27490, 869, 11330, 22136, 208721, 243, 921, 1552, 266, 97647, 
489, 9644, 743, 491, 62900, 179754, 23188, 1111, 9760, 27824, 
193337, 228, 769, 858, 159, 83213, 330, 10410, 869, 474, 54946, 
188765, 30850, 973, 9485, 22181, 196101, 218, 1012, 1482, 292, 
91553, 392, 9989, 724, 431, 50766, 201313, 25308, 1095, 10801, 
25842, 206138, 246, 836, 1199, 210, 94152, 362, 8414, 624, 457, 
55365)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-64L))
```

Code:

```
library(networkD3)
library(tidyverse)

  
 dat  = dat %>% filter(time_period == '4 -> 5') 
 
 
 nodes <- data.frame(name=c(as.character(dat$source), as.character(dat$target)) %>% unique())
  
 
 dat$IDsource=match(dat$source, nodes$name)-1 
 dat$IDtarget=match(dat$target, nodes$name)-1
  
      
  # Make the Network
  sankeyNetwork(Links = dat, Nodes = nodes,
                Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
                Value = "count", NodeID = "name", 
                sinksRight=FALSE, nodeWidth=40, fontSize=13, nodePadding=20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it a go using `ggalluvial`. Each section is plotted quite independently. The height difference between borders can be fixed by adding empty rows.

```r
library(ggalluvial)
library(dplyr)

head(dat)
# time_period source target  count
#  <chr>       <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 1 -> 2      A      A      200573
#2 1 -> 2      A      B       27490
#3 1 -> 2      A      C         869
#4 1 -> 2      A      D       11330
#5 1 -> 2      B      A       22136
#6 1 -> 2      B      B      208721

# re-format into long data format
dat2 = NULL
for (i in 1:4) {
  tem <- dat %>%
    filter(time_period == paste0(i," -> ", i+1)) %>%
    {data.frame(
      alluvium = paste(i, c(seq(nrow(.)), 
                            seq(nrow(.)))), # same alluvium for each pair
      time = c(rep(i+ifelse(i>1,0.0001,0), nrow(.)), 
               rep(i+1, nrow(.))), # +0.0001 to avoid overlapping with previous section
      count = c(.$count, .$count),
      group = c(.$source, .$target)
    )
    }
  dat2 <- rbind(dat2, tem)
}

# padding missing values to match borders between sections
for (i in 1:4) {
  # right side missing
  if (i < 4) {
    count_this <- dat %>%
      filter(time_period == paste0(i," -> ", i+1)) %>%
      group_by(target) %>%
      summarise(count = sum(count)) %>%
      .$count
    
    count_right <- dat %>%
      filter(time_period == paste0(i+1," -> ", i+2)) %>%
      group_by(source) %>%
      summarise(count = sum(count)) %>%
      .$count
    
    count_max <- pmax(count_this, count_right)
    
    dat2 = dat2 %>%
      rbind(., data.frame(
        alluvium = paste(i, "right_missing", seq(4)),
        time = c(rep(i+1, 4)),
        count = count_max - count_this, # padding if less count than the right side
        group = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
      )
      )
  }

  # left side missing
  if (i > 1) {
    count_left <- dat %>%
      filter(time_period == paste0(i-1," -> ", i)) %>%
      group_by(target) %>%
      summarise(count = sum(count)) %>%
      .$count
    
    count_this <- dat %>%
      filter(time_period == paste0(i," -> ", i+1)) %>%
      group_by(source) %>%
      summarise(count = sum(count)) %>%
      .$count
    
    count_max <- pmax(count_left, count_this)
    
    dat2 = dat2 %>%
      rbind(., data.frame(
        alluvium = paste(i, "left_missing", seq(4)),
        time = c(rep(i+0.0001, 4)),
        count = count_max - count_this,  # padding if less count than the left side
        group = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
      )
      )
  }
}

dat2 %>%
  filter(count>0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = count, stratum = group, alluvium = alluvium)) +
  geom_flow(aes(fill = group)) +
  geom_stratum(data = dat2[dat2$time%%1==0,], aes(fill = group), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_text(data = dat2[dat2$time%%1==0,], stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]